# How to calculate the `children's` height pefectly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am calulating the `childrens` height, to add the scrollbar to the container. but it's not come as perfect. any one help me to calculate the childrens height perfectly?

here is my js :

```
var p= "</p>Some testing text</p>";

var getAllHeight = function (content) {
    var allHeight = 0;
    $('#container').children().not('.content').each(function(){
        allHeight += $(this).outerHeight(true);
    });
    return allHeight;
}

var addHeight = function () {
    var content = $('.content');
    var allHeight = getAllHeight(content);
    var rest = $('#container').innerHeight() - allHeight;

    if(content.outerHeight() > rest) {
        content.css('height', (content.outerHeight() - allHeight ));
    }

    console.log(allHeight, content.height(), content.outerHeight(),content.innerHeight())
};

$('button').click(function(){
    $('.content').append(p);
    addHeight();
});

<div id="container">
    <div>
        <h2>Heading</h2>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h2>Heading</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="content">

    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        Footer
    </div>
    <div class="button"><button>Add</button></div>
</div>
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/doesfmnm/4/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is CSS issue due to [collapsing margins](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing) (read "Parent and first/last child" case) on `div>h2` structure. Since `div` containers don't have any padding, margin or border, their margins collapse to accommodate inner margin. Simple fix is to set some padding on them or border or set `h2` to inline-block.

Another issue is that when there is not enough space you should set `content` height to `rest`.

```
if (content.outerHeight() > rest) {
    content.css('height', rest);
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/doesfmnm/5/